# Hide scrollbar Android KitKat 4.4

Tags: android, jquery, css, phonegap-build

My phonegap build app is working fine on all versions of android from 4.0.4 to 4.3.

When I tested it on KitKat 4.4 some pages where content doesn't cover the screen height has got scrollbars shown. On pages where content needs to be scrolled scrollbars hidden.

I don't know what the problem is and how to solve it.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix it? Or is there a css code (not `overflow: ...;`) or jQuery script how to prevent it or make a virtual object with a couple of pixels more than the height of the screen.

![Screenshot][1]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUaBS.png

Comment: I'd reccomend posted what you've tried, and clarify it a bit, struggling to understand the problem.

Comment: Got the same problem... Scrollviews that do not cover the complete screen now have scrollbars even if there is nothing to scroll

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From here: https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/webview/overview

> Android 4.4 (KitKat) includes a new WebView component based on the
>   Chromium open source project.

It means that Android 4.4 (KitKat) now uses Chrome for WebView-based apps. On Chrome, when using the css property "overflow: scroll", the browser displays the scrollbar (even if content is smaller than the parent view).

Changing "overflow: scroll" to "overflow: auto" fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
SELECTOR::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```